# Why $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

The definition from the book I am using state: $f(x):D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is said to be *uniformly continuous* provided that whenever $\{u_n\}$ and $\{v_n\}$ are sequences in $D$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(u_n-v_n)=0$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(f(u_n)-f(v_n))=0$.

To show $f(x)=x^2$ is not uniformly continuous, I know I can pick $\{u_n\}=\{n\}$ and $\{v_n\} = \{n+1/n\}$.

What if I don't know those two sequences or any sequences that I can apply to show $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous.

---

Assume that $f(x)=x^2$ is uniformly continuous from $D$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then let $\{u_n\}$ and $\{v_n\}$ in $D$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|u_n-v_n|=0$; by the definition, we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|f(u_n)-f(v_n)|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |u_n^2-v_n^2|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |(u_n-v_n)(u_n+v_n)|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |(u_n-v_n)||(u_n+v_n)|=0$$

---

I don't quite see a contradiction, can someone tell me where I did wrong? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The last $=$ is where you made an error. Why should it be $0$?

Comment: @Nex $\lim|u_n-v_n||u_n+v_n|=\lim|u_n-v_n|\cdot\lim|u_n+v_n|$

Comment: $\frac{1}{n} \times n^2 \to 0$?

Comment: @Simple $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n b_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n \lim_{n\to \infty} b_n$ only if both limits exist.

Answer (score 2):

Under the definition, to prove that $x \mapsto x^{2}$ is not uniformly continuous it suffices to find some sequences $(u_{n}), (v_{n})$ such that $u_{n} - v_{n} \to 0$ and $(u_{n}-v_{n})(u_{n} + v_{n})$ does not; consider the sequences $(u_{n}), (v_{n})$ defined by
$$
u_{n} := n^{2} + \frac{1}{n}, v_{n} := n^{2}
$$
for all $n \geq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

**First question**

If you don't have a specific sequence in mind, you can prove that $f(x) = x^2$ is not uniformly continuous using the definition of uniform continuity and a bit of algebra.

The definition of uniform continuity is that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x, y \in D$, if $|x - y| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon$.

Let's show that this property doesn't hold for $f(x) = x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}$. For the sake of contradiction, suppose $f$ were uniformly continuous. Then for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there would exist a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, if $|x - y| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(y)| = |x^2 - y^2| < \varepsilon$.

We can simplify $|x^2 - y^2|$ using the difference of squares to get $|x - y||x + y| < \varepsilon$. This leads to $|x + y| < \varepsilon / \delta$.

Here's the contradiction: for any given $\delta > 0$, we can choose $x$ and $y$ such that $|x - y| < \delta$ but $|x + y|$ is as large as we want (for example, let $x = R$ and $y = R + \delta / 2$ for a large $R > 0$). This contradicts the inequality $|x + y| < \varepsilon / \delta$.

Therefore, $f(x) = x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

**Second question**
The assumption that $f(x) = x^2$ is uniformly continuous from $D$ to $\mathbb{R}$ seems to lead to a contradiction given your analysis. Your argument seems to try to prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous by showing that whenever $|u_n - v_n| \rightarrow 0$, we have $|f(u_n) - f(v_n)| \rightarrow 0$.

However, your argument does not hold for every pair of sequences $(u_n, v_n)$ that satisfies $|u_n - v_n| \rightarrow 0$. It's true that $|(u_n - v_n)(u_n + v_n)| = |f(u_n) - f(v_n)| \rightarrow 0$, but only if $|(u_n + v_n)|$ does not increase faster than $|u_n - v_n|$ decreases.

The problem is that the term $|(u_n + v_n)|$ is not necessarily bounded for every pair of sequences $(u_n, v_n)$ that satisfies $|u_n - v_n| \rightarrow 0$. Consider the pair of sequences you mentioned: $u_n = n$ and $v_n = n + \frac{1}{n}$. Here, $|u_n - v_n| \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, but $|(u_n + v_n)| = |2n + \frac{1}{n}| \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

The function $f(x) = x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, which can be shown by counterexample, as you mentioned. It's important to remember that a function is uniformly continuous if and only if the condition holds for all pairs of sequences $(u_n, v_n)$ that satisfies $|u_n - v_n| \rightarrow 0$, not just some.